# React live update input text form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, textfield

I am working on transforming an excel spreadsheet into a webapp. One issue I have is how to live update the "first-commission" value which is a nested child. How would I make that multiplication possible and update the state on textfield change without a submit? (Textfield is a material-ui component)

```
this.state = {
   personalValues: [
     {"first-commission":  (average-policy * closing * weeks)  },
     {cancels: 0},
     {"average-policy": 0},
     {weeks: 0},
     {presentationsPW: 0},
     {closing: 0},
     {appsPW: 0}
   ]
```

The Component (classNames are same as personalValues names, personalFormValues is a fill in array)

```
<ul key={i}>
    <label>
      {personalFormValues.name[i]}<br/>
      <TextField
        className='${personalFormValues.class[i]}'
        type="number"
        value={this.state.personalValues['${personalFormValues.class[i]}']}
        onChange={this.handleFormChange}
        pattern="[0-9]*"
        required />
    </label>
```

The form change method

```
handleFormChange(event){
  this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value})
}
```

I included a gif for clarification

[via GIPHY](https://giphy.com/gifs/1AIw43dsese4XyvEJR)

Answer (score 2):

Simply change your `handleFormChange` to update `first-commission` each time a form is touched:

```
handleFormChange(e){
  this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value}, () => {
    const {
      average-policy,
      weeks,
      closing,
    } = this.state;

    this.setState({ 'first-commission': (average-policy * closing * weeks) });   
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a `name="personalValues"` on your textfield input that corresponds with the name you are using to store the value in the state.

```
 this.state = {

     personalValues: ""
 }

 <TextField
    className='${personalFormValues.class[i]}'
    type="number"
    value={this.state.personalValues['${personalFormValues.class[i]}']}
    onChange={this.handleFormChange}
    pattern="[0-9]*"
    name="personalValues"
    required />
```